# Facebook SSO integration violations

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

Not so long ago i have integrated Facebook's SSO into my mobile app. Few days ago i've received an email from the Facebook titled: `XXX is deactivated due to violations`.

The email states that the violation is caused by the [Platform Term 6.a.i.1.](https://developers.facebook.com/terms/dfc_platform_terms/#datasecurity) which is `Meet or exceed industry standards given the sensitivity of the Platform Data`

The email continues with:

> To resolve this violation, provide the evidence described in the 'Protecting Platform Data Stored on Organizational Devices and Removable Media From Loss' section of Platform [Term 6.a.i Data Security Requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/maintaining-data-access/data-protection-assessment/data-security#protecting-platform-data-stored-on-organizational-devices-and-removable-media-from-loss).

The link then points to:

> ##### Protecting Platform Data Stored on Organizational Devices and Removable Media from Loss
>
> Question: Specifically concerning data stored on organizational and
> personal devices: Do you enforce encryption at rest, or do you have in
> place policies and rules to reduce the risk of data loss, for all
> Platform Data stored on these devices?

My application allows an offline use of the credentials retrieved from the Facebook's API (name & email). Additionally to offline/local storage we keep it on our own backend for further processing.

Reading further the [Term 6.a.i Data Security Requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/maintaining-data-access/data-protection-assessment/data-security#protecting-platform-data-stored-on-organizational-devices-and-removable-media-from-loss) it states the intent as:

> If a developer allows Platform Data on devices like employee laptops
> or removable storage (e.g., USB drives), that data is at high risk of
> unauthorized access if the device is lost or stolen. Developers should
> take steps to limit this risk.

But i do not see any correlation with why my app is doing and what the Facebook requires me to do (expect the local offline storage of email & username).

Could someone explain in simpler terms what i'm doing wrong, and what the Facebook needs from me?

Comment: You need to talk to Facebook and/or a lawyer.  We have no way of knowing how they interpret their guidelines.  In addition, whoever you talk to would need detailed descriptions of exactly what data is being stored how and where, your current level of depth in this post doesn't give enough details for anyone to know if it's ok or not